# Calling macro from a macro call

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why doesn't the following code output the maximum of three numbers?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define max(a,b) (a>b)?(a):(b)
#define min(a,b) (b>a)?(a):(b)

int main()
{
    printf("%d",max(2,max(1,4)));
    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
Output: 2
```

Is calling a macro within a macro call not possible?

Comment: @M.M fixed it to work as a small working example.

Comment: @M.M The above code works perfectly [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SyNHpFKF7)

Comment: @M.M Yes my bad, a bracket was missing. Fixed it.

Comment: Done, I was in a bit of hurry so messed up a little bit.

Comment: the problem is due to the fact that the ternary operator `?` has lower precedence than the relational operators, in this case `>`, and when the macros are expended at compile time, the `>` is getting evaluated sooner than you expect.  So, when you add the parentheses as in @chux answer, the operators will get evaluated in the order that you expect.

Comment: There is no such thing as a macro call. A preprocessor macro operates by substituting the macro name and parameters with source code from the macro definition. The result is actual source code where the macro is used, not any sort of run-time call. (It is often misstated that preprocessor macros perform text substitution, but that is incorrect. They substitute preprocessor tokens, which are essentially text that has been grouped into identifiers, C operators such as `++`, and other units.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is calling a macro within a macro call not possible?

It is possible to nest macro calls

---

To get the desire functionality, place a `()` around each parameter and a `()` around the entire expression.

```
// #define max(a,b) (a>b)?(a):(b)
#define max(a,b) (((a)>(b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

---

Without judicious use of `()`, code may not evaluate as expected when the argument is non-trivial as is `b` in the outer call of `max(a,b)` in  `max(2,max(1,4))`

Answer (score 1):

`max(2, max(1,4))` expands to `(2> (1>4)?(1):(4)  )?(2):(  (1>4)?(1):(4)  )` **NOTICE** `2> (1>4)?` is `2 > false == 2 > 0` which is true. So 2 is the value.

to fix this, add some parentheses :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
#define min(a,b) (((b)>(a))?(a):(b))

int main()
{
    printf("%d",max(2, max(1,4)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works and my code doesn't? The parenthesis solution does not seem to be really intuitive to me as of now.

Comment: `,max(2, max(1,4))` expands to `(2> (1>4)?(1):(4)  )?(2):(  (1>4)?(1):(4)  )` **NOTICE** `2> (1>4)?` is `2 > false == 2 > 0` which is true. So 2 is the value. @PrathuBaronia

Comment: The outer `()` are a good first step, yet `(a>b)` deserves `()` about `a,b` before the compare occurs --> `((a)>(b))`

Comment: @chux Thats a good catch, it just happens to work for this example without them. Ill add that fix, thx